# How can I compute the HTTP origin string from URL in node.js?

Tags: node.js

On client, I can just do `new URL(url).origin`, but `URL` does not seem to be available in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`url.parse`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) and then use the `protocol`, `hostname`, `port` properties.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
var urlModule = require('url');

function getOrigin(url) {
  var parsed = urlModule.parse(url);
  return urlModule.format(_.pick(parsed, 'protocol', 'hostname', 'port'));
}
```